# casting column of a dataframe in pySpark using selectExpr

Tags: pyspark

I have to cast the column datatypes and need to pass some default values to a new column in my dataframe.
I have tried below approach but failed in loading.

I have a list:

```
a = ["cast(col_1 as double) as col_1", "cast('DIM' as string) as new_colmn"]

for items in a:
  select_var = items + ","

select_var = select_var.strip(",")  # It will remove the last unwanted commas.
```

Finally im passing this to the dataframe to cast the old column and create new column as passed in variable:

```
df2 = df1.selectExpr("*", select_var)
```

But, Im getting the required output.Could any one help me over here??? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the List in selectExpr, see example below:

> Create Session and sample data frame

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

sample_df = spark.createDataFrame([("123","abc")],["col_1", "col2"])
```

> Print Schema before Type Casting

```
print(sample_df.schema) # Schema before Type Casting
```

> Create Type Casting expression

```
expression = ["cast(col_1 as double) as col_1", "cast('DIM' as string) as new_colmn"]
```

> Apply Type Casting expression

```
casted_df=sample_df.selectExpr(expression)
```

> Print Schema after Type Casting

```
print(casted_df.schema) # Schema after Type Casting
casted_df.show()
```

> Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks, but for the column datatype change, i'm getting null values. `"cast(col_1 as double) as col_1"`

I have tried putting `"cast(col('col_1') as double) as col_1"`. But this one is also having a problem..please check and let me know ??

Comment: It is working for the creation of new column with  type we passed, but it is not working for the type case of the column which is already present in dataframe.

Comment: @SureshGudimetla what kind of values do you have in col_1 ? Ideally it should work as shown in the example above. You can try printing the original value of col_1 and then type casted values as "cast(col_1 as double) as col_1_cast" and debug it if its working or not.

Comment: @suresh can you please provide the sample data for col_1 where it's returning null values